# Drake source install on Ubuntu 20.04: Could NOT find Python

Tags: cmake, drake

I'm trying to build drake from source on Ubuntu 20.04 by following instructions from [here](https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html). I already checked that my system meets all the requirements, and was ale to successfully run the mandatory platform-specific setup script (and it completed saying: 'install_prereqs: success'). However, when I try to run cmake to build the python bindings, I'm confronted with the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS NumPy) (found
  suitable exact version "3.8.10")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2214 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython.cmake:304 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:240 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I can't seem to think of any reason why this is happening (I made sure to remove conda from my PATH variable following the note [here](https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#installation). Any help around this issue is much appreciated!

EDIT: Want to mention that I'm trying to install Drake from [this PR](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/16147) that includes a feature I need access to.

Comment: For the historical record, please edit your post above to state which git revision of Drake you're trying to use.

Comment: The Drake code just does `find_package(Python 3 EXACT MODULE REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development Interpreter NumPy)`, which seems like bog-standardard CMake to me.  It's probably worth adding the "#cmake" tag to this question, since it's really a "why does CMake hate me" question, not really a Drake question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On another tack, you could try to temporarily work around the problem by doing (in Drake) a `bazel run //:install -- /path/to/somewhere` to install Drake, and thus skipping the CMake stuff that seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some diagnostic output from my Ubuntu 20.04 system.  Can you run the same, and check to see if anything looks different?

```
jwnimmer@call-cps:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python

jwnimmer@call-cps:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

jwnimmer@call-cps:~$ file /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3: symbolic link to python3.8

jwnimmer@call-cps:~$ dpkg -l python3-numpy 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version           Architecture Description
+++-==============-=================-============-============================================
ii  python3-numpy  1:1.17.4-5ubuntu3 amd64        Fast array facility to the Python 3 language

jwnimmer@call-cps:~$ ls -l /usr/include/python3.8/numpy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Feb 18  2020 /usr/include/python3.8/numpy -> ../../lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy

jwnimmer@call-cps:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy | head
total 388
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   164 Jun 15  2019 arrayobject.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3509 Jun 15  2019 arrayscalars.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1878 Aug 30  2019 halffloat.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 61098 Feb 18  2020 __multiarray_api.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56456 Feb 18  2020 multiarray_api.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11496 Oct 15  2019 ndarrayobject.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65018 Nov  8  2019 ndarraytypes.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1861 Jun 15  2019 _neighborhood_iterator_imp.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6786 Aug 30  2019 noprefix.h
```

Comment: Ran all of these commands and everything looks exactly the same